# Перебрать state в mutations через foreach или map

Tags: javascript, vuex

В Vuex есть стейт вида

```
state: {
  messageUserName: '',
  messageUserEmail: '',
  messageUserPhone: '',
  messageTitleVal: '',
  messageTextVal: '',
},
```

и мутаторы вида

```
mutations: {
  setMessageUserName: (state, messageUserName) => 
    state.messageUserName = messageUserName,
```

Как написать мутатор, пробегающийся по стейту и приводящие его значения к пустой строке ?

Answer (score 0):

Для плоского объекта состояния (как в вопросе):

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    messageUserName: 'a',
    messageUserEmail: 'b',
    messageUserPhone: 'c',
    messageTitleVal: 'd',
    messageTextVal: 'e',
  },
  mutations: {
    TO_EMPTY_STRING(state, fields = []) {
      if (!fields.length)
        fields = Object.keys(state); 
      fields.forEach(k => state[k] = ''); 
    }
  }, 
}); 

console.log(store.state); 
store.commit('TO_EMPTY_STRING'); 
console.log(store.state);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex/dist/vuex.min.js"></script>
```

Если же целевые свойства будут вложены, то потребуется немного простой рекурсии по объектам (которую лучше реализовать локальной хелпер-функцией в той же мутации).

Comment: Осторожнее с аргументом `fields` - если в состоянии не окажется указанного свойства, оно создастся нереактивным. Можно было бы использовать `Vue.set`, но это создает соблазн инициализировать состояние мутацией (очень плохая практика)... если нет доверия к вызывающему коду, то лучше уж дополнительная проверка через `hasOwnProperty` или сравнением типа с `undefined`.